# How to stop useEffect from going infinite loop or setState inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am dispatching action in side `useEffect` after dispatching I want to get state from redux state and pass this to local state inside component But the problem is whenever i try to do this It either goes to infinite loop or doesn't setState at all. I don't know how to solve this. Any help would be great.

This is my code.

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);



 const DataReceived = (state) =>                              <--- Here I am getting state from store.
    state.AllUsers.Seller.sellerDetails.data._embedded;
  const selectedData = useSelector(DataReceived, shallowEqual);
  const selectedDataAgain = selectedData
    ? selectedData.vendorUserResourceList
    : null;

  console.log("selectedDataAgain", selectedDataAgain);    <--- this one is working this shows array of data.
  console.log("selectedDataAgainTable", tableData);

  const { GetUserLoadVendors } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    GetUserLoadVendors(access_token);          <--- this is the actions
    setTableData(selectedDataAgain);           <--- here am trying to set State
  }, []);
```

When i add optional second argument in useEffect like `[GetUserLoadVendors, selectedDataAgain]` it goes to infinite loop. If i don't add any dependency it doesn't setStates.

Answer (score 0):

Bring `selectedDataAgain` into `useEffect` and includes `selectedData` as dependency

```js
const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);



 const DataReceived = (state) =>                              <--- Here I am getting state from store.
    state.AllUsers.Seller.sellerDetails.data._embedded;
  const selectedData = useSelector(DataReceived, shallowEqual);
 
  console.log("selectedDataAgainTable", tableData);

  const { GetUserLoadVendors } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
   const selectedDataAgain = selectedData
    ? selectedData.vendorUserResourceList
    : null;

  console.log("selectedDataAgain", selectedDataAgain);    // this one is working this shows array of data.
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    GetUserLoadVendors(access_token);          <--- this is the actions
    setTableData(selectedDataAgain);           <--- here am trying to set State
  }, [selectedData]);
```

I don't think you want `useEffect` to trigger when `GetUserLoadVendors` change, if you want so, want can includes `GetUserLoadVendors` s a dependency but make sure you want wrap it with useCallback at the place it is created (parent component).

Answer (score 0):

You ideally do not need copy data from props into state since its directly derivable from redux state.

However if you need to, you should write the update logic in separate useEffect like

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([]);

const DataReceived = (state) =>                     
    state.AllUsers.Seller.sellerDetails.data._embedded;
const selectedData = useSelector(DataReceived, shallowEqual);
const selectedDataAgain = selectedData
    ? selectedData.vendorUserResourceList
    : null;

  console.log("selectedDataAgain", selectedDataAgain);  
  console.log("selectedDataAgainTable", tableData);

  const { GetUserLoadVendors } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    GetUserLoadVendors(access_token);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
      setTableData(selectedDataAgain);

  }, [selectedData]) // Dependency is selectedData and not selectedDataAgain since reference of selectedDataAgain changes on every render whereas it doesn't for selectedData
```